# Models for the given FOL statement

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

Consider the following FOL sentence:

$\phi = \exists x \forall y \exists z ((x=y) \lor (P(x,y,z) \land \lnot P(y,x,z) ) $

It can be proven that for any natural number n > 0 there exits a model of size n for the above sentence. (Please correct me here if I am wrong. This should be provable using induction.).

Now imagine a FOL sentence that **does not use = (and similar) predicate**. And if such a sentence has a model of size n can I claim that the sentence will essentially have a model of size n+1  ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. If there is a model $\mathcal M$ of size $n$ of any sentence $\phi$ that does not use = then you can take any element $a$ of $\mathcal M$ (using the fact that $n>0$) and let $\mathcal N$ be $\mathcal M$ with an additional element $b$ which has all the same properties as $a$. Then $\mathcal N$ still satisfies $\phi$.

If $n=0$, however, the answer is no: the sentence
$$\exists x(P(x)\vee\neg P(x))\longrightarrow \exists x\exists y(P(x)\wedge\neg P(y))$$
has a model of size 0 but no model of size 1.

Comment: By syaing b has all properties of a you are trying to say add "another a" and since our FOL cant use "=" we will get away with it.  

But I feel you have ignored the fact that : 

size of a model means the cardinality of it's universe. Universe is a set and hence each member of universe has to be distinct isnt it ? 

Comment: Well then consider the sentence $\forall x(P(x)\vee\neg P(x))$. This has a model of size 2 but no model of size 3 in your sense. Because of the three elements, two have to agree about whether they satisfy $P$ and so there is nothing left to distinguish them.

Comment: @Akshar Prabhu Desai:  $b$ having the same properties as $a$ just means that $b$ is indistinguishable from $a$ with respect to the relations definable in the structure under consideration (except for equality, which we are not allowed to use).  
They are not indistinguishable as members of the set-theoretic universe.  
For instance, $i$ and $-i$ are indistinguishable as complex numbers,
since there is an automorphism carrying one to the other, yet $\mathbb C$ is a set.  Or take the structure with two elements $0$ and $1$ and no relations, functions and constants whatsoever.